# A man wins the jackpot at a slot machine

Tags: identify-this-movie, action

So I remember watching this movie a couple of years back on my laptop, it involves a man who is chased by someone (I think) and enters a casino in which he has a earpiece and the person tells him to go to the biggest casino machine I think.

The slot machine was huge and the person on the earpiece told him to go on that machine next and the security were watching him on the cameras and when the main actor sat at the machine everybody looked at him then when he won I think confetti came out of the machine?

American movie I think and the person tries to run away from authorities?
Any help? 21st century movie? Involves guns?

Comment: Are there any action movies in casinos *without* earpieces and guns? ;) Please give us more details, is what I'm saying. Do you remember the plot? Possible actors or what they looked like? Level of violence? Anything?

Comment: I really cant remember much but the slot machine was huge and the person on the earpiece told him to go on that machine next and the security were watching him on the cameras and when the main actor sat at the machine everybody looked at him then when he won i think confetti came out of the machine?

Answer (score 9):

Possibly [The Echelon Conspiracy](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1124039/combined) from 2009 with Shane West, Edward Burns and Ving Rhames.

> Max Peterson is a globe-trotting techno-whiz who installs security systems on computers. He receives an anonymous gift: a phone which sends messages that enable him to win at a casino. Max soon finds himself pursed by hit men, the casino's security chief, and a CIA operative. Who's sending Max messages?

At one point, he's wearing an earpiece that instructs him to go to the biggest slot machine in a casino. He's watched by the security team as he wins the jackpot & they come after him. No confetti, though. Here's the trailer:

Comment: @SpartaRamoHD No problem! Don't forget to click on the check mark to mark this as 'solved'.